# Cannot curl JDK from oracle site anymore

Tags: java, oracle, curl

I'm attempting to obtain jre using:

```
curl -Lv -b "oraclelicense=a" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u65-b17/jre-8u65-linux-x64.tar.gz -o jre-8u65-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

OR

```
curl -jkLv -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u65-b17/jre-8u65-linux-x64.tar.gz -o jre-8u65-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

However, the downloaded file is 7.1kB in size. Has anyone any ideas as to why this has stopped working. It was working last night. Thanks in advance.

I have tried various jdks, I'd like to use curl only.

Comment: Honestly I'm just going to download a copy and place it in Google Drive and curl from there, or map it in as needed for docker builds.  Oracle is ridiculous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has worked for me; note that the value 'd54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163' seems to be constant for whatever reason and hasn't timed out yet:

```
curl -jkL -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jre-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz -o jre-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Comment: using `curl -L -b "oraclelicense=a" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jre-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz -o jre-8u131-b11-linux-x64.tar.gz` as a little more elegant than passing header, but will accept as answer.

Comment: How did you get the hash?

Comment: @heez See the link at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jre-8u131-oth-JPRXXXjre-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz.

Answer (score 4):

the below should work.

```
curl -LOb "oraclelicense=a" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u172-b11/a58eab1ec242421181065cdc37240b08/jre-8u172-linux-x64.tar.gz
```